# Elide copy/move when wrapping a function receiving a prvalue

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I am trying to create a wrapper function that has the exact same interface as the function that it wraps, with zero runtime cost overhead.

In the example code below, is it possible to design `my_function_wrapped` in a way so that it has the same interface as `my_function`, so that calling it with the exact same arguments as to `my_function` always yield the same results?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct SMyStruct
{
    SMyStruct() { cout << "SMyStruct constructed" << std::endl;}
    SMyStruct(SMyStruct&& Other) { cout << "SMyStruct moved" << std::endl;}
    SMyStruct(const SMyStruct& Other) { cout << "SMyStruct copied" << std::endl; }
    ~SMyStruct() {cout << "SMyStruct destroyed" << std::endl;}
};

void my_function(SMyStruct Arg)
{
}

template<typename T>
void my_function_wrapped(T&& Arg)
{
    my_function(std::forward<T>(Arg));

    // Some extra logic here that doesn't use Arg
}

int main()
{
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Direct call to my_function:" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    
    my_function(SMyStruct());

    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Wrapped call to my_function:" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;

    my_function_wrapped(SMyStruct());

    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs:

```
-----------------------------
Direct call to my_function:
-----------------------------
SMyStruct constructed
SMyStruct destroyed
-----------------------------
Wrapped call to my_function:
-----------------------------
SMyStruct constructed
SMyStruct moved
SMyStruct destroyed
SMyStruct destroyed
```

I realize that copy/move is elided on the first call to `my_function` because `SMyStruct()` is a prvalue. Is it possible to wrap this call in `my_function_wrapped` and still get the elided copy/move? Is there any zero-cost way to abstract away the call?

godbolt-link to the code: https://godbolt.org/z/joGTTe64f

Thanks!

Comment: `std::forward<T>(Arg)` is not a prvalue.

Comment: @JasonLiam Exactly. So is it possible to forward it somehow to get the result that I'm after?

Comment: `Arg` inside the function is an lvalue and `std::forward<T>(Arg)` is an rvalue, so that the move ctor is used(as also shown in the output of your program). I think this is enough and there is no need to elide anything here.

Comment: @JasonLiam That's correct, but I'm trying to achieve a zero-cost abstraction for the call. The direct call now will be faster than the wrapped call. Is there a way to create this abstraction without any performance penalty?

Comment: Is this question based on some real problem you have, or is it just about curiosity? Being curious is all fine and well, but please state it in the question itself. Otherwise if you have an underlying problem that you need to solve, please ask about that directly instead. Otherwise this question is just an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @user3725041 The problem here(if any) is that you're trying to treat an `xvalue` like an `prvalue`. You get the output which is the expected output according to the standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are right. The real problem is that I want to create a function that returns a wrapper function/lambda that can be used exactly as if it was the original function. I will update the post to clarify

Comment: Maybe stupid but, what about just returning/using the original function instead of a wrapper ? I fail to understand the need for such a thing. If it's just a matter a names, maybe you could try something with `using` directives.

Comment: @Fareanor Because what I would really want to do is to have extra "hidden" logic in the wrapper function. I should have made this clear in my original post.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to chain copy elision of prvalues through function calls like this.

Copy elision only works because the caller can construct the function parameter knowing where it needs to place it from the declaration of the function and the calling convention used.

The original caller doesn't know that you are going to simply forward the argument to another function in the body and therefore it cannot know that it is supposed to construct the object into the deeper stack frame. C++ is also designed in such a way that functions can be compiled individually only having to know the declarations of other functions (constant expression evaluation aside). Definitions of the functions don't even have to be available where a call happens.

Allowing this would require some additional language feature to annotate a function declaration to inform callers where they have to construct the parameter and I think it would be difficult to find a good specification for such a feature.

What you can do is pass the arguments for your constructor, or more generally a callable object which creates your prvalue, around, e.g.

```
template<typename F>
void my_function_wrapped(F&& f)
{
    my_function(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f)));
}

//...

my_function_wrapped([]{ return SMyStruct(); });
```

The lambda can capture arguments to the constructor if needed.

(Note however that all of this requires C++17. You also tagged C++14, but in C++14 there was no guaranteed copy elision in any of the situations under discussion anyway.)

Comment: Thank you for a very helpful answer! Is it possible to design my_function_wrapped in a way so that it has the same interface as my_function? So that calling it with the exact same arguments as to my_function always yield the same results.

Comment: @user3725041 Only with the help of macros. To get the same syntax `my_function_wrapped` would need to be a macro. It is also not uncommon to use macros which turn an expression into a perfectly-forwarding lambda with reference-capture, correctly forwarding `noexcept` specifier, etc, so that the function can be called as `my_function_wrapped(LAMBDA(SMyStruct()))` or such.

Comment: @user3725041 Of course you can get the same syntax if you modify the original function to also accept a generator instead of the type directly, but I think that is not what you intend.

Comment: It's a bit disappointing that it requires a macro to do it. I would have hoped that it could be achieved with some template metaprogramming magic. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your real case (or if there is a real case to begin with), though in your example there is really no point in passing the `SMyStruct` to the wrapper to forward it to the actual function (because `SMyStruct` has no state). If instead you forward parameters for the constructor you get desired output:

```
template<typename...T>
void my_function_wrapped(T&&... Arg)
{
    my_function(SMyStruct(std::forward<T>(Arg)...));
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7jjP7KaEr)

Comment: This is helpful! Can my_function_wrapped be designed in a way so that the interface to it is exactly the same as for my_function? So that the arguments passed to the my_function_wrapper always yield the same results as if it was passed to my_function.